# reading different files from the subroutine depending on the input

Tags: fortran, readfile, subroutine

I have a piece of code in fortran. I have the files dumped in subroutine. Now I want to call the specific file from the subroutine which depends on m. for eg if m=3 it should read filename(3) and if m=6 it should read filename(6). It is simply not working. Can somebody help me to fix this?

```
Program main
implicit none
integer,parameter :: dp=kind(1.d0)
real,parameter::m=3
real(dp), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: s

 call My_Reader(m) 
 allocate (s(m,m))
 read(m*10,*) s
 print*,s

 SUBROUTINE My_Reader(m)
 integer,parameter :: dp=kind(1.d0)
 character (len=256)::filename(m)
 integer , intent(in) :: m
 filename(6)='C:\Users\spaudel\Documents\S6.txt'
 filename(3)='C:\Users\spaudel\Documents\S3.txt'
 OPEN (unit=m*10,FILE=fileName(m),status='old', action='read')
 END SUBROUTINE My_Reader
```

in the above program it should print s( my filename is m*m matrix) but sometimes it prints sometimes not. I am using gfortran.

Comment: dont forget to `close(m*10)` the opened file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the filename array is given as `(m)`, which is the dummy argument for which of the files you want to read.

So if, for example, you `call My_Reader(3)`, it will only initialize a 3-element array for `filename` and then anything can happen when you write something to the 6th element.

You could simply fix the size of the `filename` array in the subroutine declaration block:

```
character(len=256) :: filename(6)
```

but I would do something completely different, I'd use a `select case` to assign the filename in the subroutine:

```
subroutine my_reader(m)
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    character(len=256) :: filename

    select case (m)
        case(3)
            filename = 'C:\Users\spaudel\Documents\S3.txt'
        case(6)
            filename = 'C:\Users\spaudel\Documents\S6.txt'
        case default
            print *, 'incorrect selection of file number: `, m
            STOP
    end select

    open(unit=m*10, file=filename, ...)
end subroutine my_reader
```

Comment: Thank you so much chw21. It worked. You saved a lot of time for me. Take care.